# Count down and reset count with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I want to show a countdown on my website. for all users but I don't want to use any backend language.
Countdown is starting from `20` and after each `1min` I am decreasing number by `1`. Means after `2mins` the value will be `18` and when it reachs at `3` the number should reset to `20`. I use the time difference to do that it count down correctly but reseting is not working. I have two functions

```
function change_html() {
  var start_number = 20;
  var start = new Date("November 11, 2020 00:00:00"); // This will get the all milisec
  var end = new Date(); // This will get the all milisec of current
  var final = (get_difference(start,end)); // This will return all the mins passed
  var new_start = (final/20); // This will get how many 20 are passed
  var new_final = new_start.toString();
  new_final = new_final.split(".");
  var final_to_show = new_start-parseInt(new_final[0]);
  final_to_show = final_to_show*20; // This will get how many numbers are remain to complete 20
  final_to_show = Math.round(((20)-final_to_show));
  document.getElementById('html_element').innerHTML = final_to_show;
}
```

And second for converting milisec to mins

```
function get_difference(start,end) {
  var difference =((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000)/60;
  return Math.abs(Math.round(difference));
}
```

I didn't want to reset the countdown on reload and the loop is endless.
I don't understand what to do with reset because it is not based on any static value it will be done in jQuery and Javascript. Please help me with this or suggest me to do it with another way.

Comment: Let me know if any there is an other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: I want to do this only in jQuery or pure javascript

Comment: you wrote : `when it reachs at 3 the number should reset to 20` --> so this only a 17mn countDown loop with numbers from 20 to 3 ?

Comment: I didn't get you point

Comment: Thanks for correcting yes you are right in the above statement

Comment: Is the countDown value should include te value `3` or not ( with this is a loop of 18 mn, without tjis a loop of 17mn)

Comment: Loop will run every `1min` and when reachs at `3` will reset from `20` and this will run on `4` or more pages. and the result will remain same.

Comment: I start again: should the value of 3 be displayed?

Comment: And one more this let supose the timer reach `16` and close the page and come after `5` or `10` min the will be `11` or `6`

Comment: Yes the number `3` will be show and after that instead of `2` will show `20`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a [setInterval method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
the most complicated was to set your countdown of 17 minutes in offset of 3 points, with a first start at 20.
...and you should have a look about how the [modulo works in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

```js
const showElement = document.getElementById('html_element')
    , one_Sec     = 1000
    , one_Min     = one_Sec * 60
    , countMax    = 20
    , countMin    = 3
    , countRange  = countMax - countMin +1
    , startDateT  = (new Date("November 11, 2020 00:00:00")).getTime()
    , timeNowDiff = () => Math.floor(Math.abs(((new Date()).getTime() -startDateT) / one_Min ))
    ;
showElement.textContent =  countMax -(timeNowDiff() % countRange)
setInterval(()=>
  {
  showElement.textContent = countMax -(timeNowDiff() % countRange)
  }
  , one_Sec *10); //  check display change every 10 seconds....
```

```html
changing every minutes : <span id="html_element" style="color:red"></span> until 3
```

Comment: It reset it self on reload I didn't want that because this page it open on max user's tab and the timer will be the same for all

Comment: no, the issue is not the same, the value change every **MINUTE** as your question is.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the loop is endless and didn't reset on reload